# localStorage resets after close browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-applications, local-storage

I've developed a local **HTML5**/**JavaScript** web application and I'm trying to store data in **localStorage**.

There are no problems if I close the webapp **tab** without closing the browser: when I re-open the webapp in a new tab I'm able to find my data in localStorage.

I see in Developer Tools (F12) -> Application that a localStorage object exists and my data are there.

If I close the browser, when I re-open the webapp (restarting the browser too) I lost everything.

I however see in Developer Tools (F12) -> Application that a localStorage object exists, but it's void.

I'm not using the `localStorage.clear()` instruction and I don't remove any item in my js code.

Browser: I'm using Google Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) (*NOT in incognito mode*).

Any idea?

Comment: You might have security settings on your browser/computer to automatically clear stuff like that. I'd try a different browser/computer, and/or play around with privacy settings.

Comment: localStorage is cleared when these conditions are met by the user under settings:

Chrome:

Setting > Privacy and Security > Clear browsing data

• Time range "All time"

• "cookies and other site data" is selected”

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried Firefox but nothing changes. I'm start thinking it is a computer configuration (maybe a policy? I don't know).

Comment: @Miaan I've changed Chrome settings to Time range "Last 4 weeks" and removed check from "cookies and other site data". No changes.

Comment: Mind showing your saving and retrieving from Local Storage?

Answer (score 3):

**Solved**:

In my JS code I was using the `window.onbeforeunload = function() {...}` instruction to prevent browser closing without saving data. I've removed this instruction.

Furthermore, I've deselected the flag "Delete browsing history on exit" from Internet Options.

Now I can restore my data from localStorage even after closing browser and restart my webapp (restarting the browser too).

Answer (score 0):

I've not used local storage much but this works for me.

The `set_data();` function sets the data in local storage. You fire this when ever you want to save the current page data.

Then when the browser closes and the page reopens, the `localStorage.getItem` finds any stored data.

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('my_data');

// for testing
alert(data);

set_data = function() {

  data = localStorage.setItem('my_data', 'whatever');

  // for testing
  alert(localStorage.getItem('my_data'));

}

delete_data = function() {

  data = localStorage.clear();

  // for testing
  alert(localStorage.getItem('my_data'));

}
```

See working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/j2y8o6rq/

Comment: Thanks @joshmoto. In my webapp I'm using a function to save data in localStorage:
`function SaveState() {
  localStorage.setItem("my_data", "value");
}`
and another function to retrieve stored data:
`function ResumeState() {
  localStorage.getItem("my_data");
}`
but it doesn't work for me: the ResumeState() function cannot find data in localStorage after browser restart.

Comment: Does my fiddle save the data in your browser when you close it and re-open it?

Comment: Have you tried passing the localStorage functions into a variable? I know it probably shouldn't matter.

Comment: Unfortunately your fiddle does not save data in my browser. I click on save, I see the alert (_whatever_) but if I close and restart the browser there is nothing in localStorage

Comment: _Have you tried passing the localStorage functions into a variable?_ Yes, in the ResumeState() function I'm using variables: `variable = localStorage.getItem("my_data");` but not in SaveState() function, should I do?

Comment: Thats interesting that my fiddle does work for you. It saves the data for me fine in chrome when I relaunch my browser. It is possible that there is nothing wrong with your code then, perhaps a browser setting or issue.

Comment: Sorry i meant, _Thats interesting that my fiddle does **not** work for you_, any luck fixing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, I'm also developing my personal web app, I fixed it with this code, I hope it helps.

```
let oldStorage = localStorage.getItem('myStorage') || '';
let newStorage = [...oldStorage];
console.log(newStorage);
```